# Como formatar o texto num TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Quero adicionar um texto formatado (pode ser em html) na minha tela TextView porém não estou conseguindo.

tenho a string nos values:

```
 <string name="lbl_explicacao">
          <![CDATA[
       <b> TESTE </b>
        TESTE
        TETES
        ]]>
    </string>
```

Tem um tal de `Html.fromHtml(String, flags)`, mas não sei como usar

O texto que eu quero fazer é meio grande, com 283 palavras, mas gostaria de formatar o título e tal..

eu tentei usar na string

```
 <string name="lbl_explicacao"> <![CDATA[
 <b>What is Lorem Ipsum?</b>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.]]>
</string>
```

Mas quando tento compilar mostra

```
<string name="lbl_explicacao">
        &lt;b> bla bla bla &lt;/b>

      ....
    </string>
```

Comment: precisa mesmo ser num TextView, pois se voce por num webview tem mais possibilidades para formatação?

Comment: Porque eu acho que apareceria como uma página web (eu acho), se aparecer como um TextView, posso tentar

Comment: voce pode configurar para parecer como quiser, pode por un fundo branco, fundo de imagem, em fim, é um mini browser que vc pode usar jvascripts, pode usar css e muito mais, veja um meu aplicativo usando webview: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.armando.raonimotores.ossonhosdeaaz.
nele, a parte de cima é java, a parte de baixo é um webview

Comment: estou pesquisando como usar. Porque na verdade eu já tenho um texto predefinido no arquivo strings.xml. ai gostaria que fosse exibido

Comment: eu tentei usar na string <string name="lbl_explicacao"> <![CDATA[]]>

Comment: Você não deve alterar a pergunta dessa maneira, agora a minha resposta ficou sem sentido. Vou reverter a edição.

Comment: Blz. É que ainda estou aprendendo a lhe dar com essa tecnologia.. Desculpe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível usar algumas das `tags` HTML para formatar texto usado em um TextView.

Elas podem ser usadas num *String Resource* ou em Java usando um dos métodos `fromHTML()` da classe [Html](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html)

- *String Resource*

  ```
  <resources>
      ...
      ...
      <string name="TextoHtml">
          <big>Texto grande</big>\n
          <small>Texto pequeno</small>\n
          <b>Texto em bold</b>\n
          <strike>Texto "riscado"</strike>\n
          Texto<sub>Texto subscrito</sub>\n
          Texto<sup>Texto sobrescrito</sup>\n
          <u>Texto Underline</u>\n
          <font color='red'>Texto em vermelho</font>\n
          <font size='20' color='green'>Texto size e cor</font>
      </string>
  </resources>
  ```
- Java

  ```
  Spanned textoHTML = Html.fromHtml("<big>Texto grande</big><br/>" +
                                    "<small>Texto pequeno</small><br/>" +
                                    "<b>Texto em bold</b><br/>" +
                                    "<strike>Texto \"riscado\"</strike><br/>" +
                                    "Texto<sub>Texto subscrito</sub><br/>" +
                                    "Texto<sup>Texto sobrescrito</sup><br/>" +
                                    "<u>Texto Underline</u><br/>" +
                                    "<font color='red'>Texto em vermelho</font><br/>" +
                                    "<font size='20' color='green'>Texto size e cor</font>");
  textView.setText(textoHTML);
  ```

Comment: Só que ao tentar emular dá um erro no resource: Ao tentar carregar no emulador, o ele dá o seguinte erro:

Error:(357) Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?
Error:(381) Unexpected end tag string   e no Html.fromHtml ele pele uma String e uma flag Html.fromHtml(String, flag), se não colocar ele disse que está deprecado.. Como resolver isso?

Comment: Não dá erro se fizer como está na resposta. Não ligue ao *deprecated* se `minSdkVersion` for inferior a API level 24.

Comment: realmente, deu certo! Muito obrigado! Então deixa eu ver se eu entendi, o texto se for grande não tem que ter espaço entre as linhas?

Comment: Não entendi o que quer dizer.

Comment: Toda vez eu dava <enter> e começava outra linha e quando ia tentar compilar dava erro

Comment: Tem de fazer assim: `"texto1" + "Texto2"`, onde está o `+` pode fazer `<enter>`

Comment: Isso no java né? Dava erro no string.xml

Comment: Se não for abusar muito. Existe como eu deixar numa <string name="campo">valor</string> esperando um valor pra eu definir no java e ser exibido depois?

Comment: Existe, mas depende como você quer usar. Abra outra pergunta e explique o que pretende fazer, mas antes veja [isto](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling)

Comment: excelente! Mutio bom

Comment: Rapaz não funcionou com o meu texto, só como seu exemplo, existe alguma limitação de caractere?

Comment: Posso te enviar meu texto pra ver onde estou errando?

Comment: Se está a tentar usar substituição(placeholders) faça outra pergunta se não edite esta pergunta e coloque lá o texto.

Comment: Pronto. Alterei o código

Comment: O problema está no uso do símbolo `%` use o atributo `formatted="false"` assim `<string name="lbl_explicacao" formatted="false">`

Comment: era isso mesmo.. exatamente isso... então eu descobri que para compilar com esse símbolo eu teria que pôr %%. Certíssimo.. Muito obrigado

Comment: Há situações em que por %% resulta, outras em que aparecem os dois, mas não me lembro quando

Comment: Se eu colocar: " Texto % ." dá certo, agora se eu colocar Texto 10% dava erro