# Android - Riscar texto em uma ListView

Tags: java, android

Criei um aplicativo de tarefas a serem feitas que são apresentadas em um ListView.

Estou usando o SQLite com uma tabela com as colunas: ID, tarefa, concluída.

Quero que quando percorrer os registros, se a coluna "concluída" for igual a "s" o texto na ListView apareça com um risco no meio dele.
Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Este código está no método recuperarTarefas() que busca todas as tarefas cadastradas no banco SQLite:

```
//Recuperar as tarefas
        Cursor cursor = bancoDeDados.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tarefas ORDER BY id DESC", null);

        //recuperar ids das colunas
        int indiceColunaId = cursor.getColumnIndex("id");
        int indiceColunaTarefa = cursor.getColumnIndex("tarefa");
        int indiceColunaConcluida = cursor.getColumnIndex("concluida");


        //cria o adaptador
        itens = new ArrayList<String>();
        itensAdaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                R.layout.items_list,
                android.R.id.text1,
                itens);

        idsTarefas = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        listaTarefas.setAdapter(itensAdaptador);

        //Lista as tarefas - quando usa o rawquery ele fica parado no ultimo registro
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (cursor != null){

            if (cursor.getString(indiceColunaConcluida) == "s"){

                itens.add(cursor.getString(indiceColunaTarefa));
                //Aqui quero colocar que o texto fica riscado

            } else {
                itens.add(cursor.getString( indiceColunaTarefa ));
                //Aqui o texto deve ficar normal (sem risco)
            }

            idsTarefas.add( Integer.parseInt( cursor.getString(indiceColunaId) ) );
            cursor.moveToNext();

        }
```

Comment: Relacionado: [Como formatar o texto num TextView](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166114/2541)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que eu fiz para riscar o texto na ListView foi o seguinte:

Ao invés de criar ArrayList do tipo String mudei para SpannableArrayList:

```
private ArrayAdapter<SpannableString> itensAdaptador;
private ArrayList<SpannableString> itens;
```

E usei a classe SpannableString para criar um texto riscado da seguinte maneira:

```
 SpannableString textoRiscado = new SpannableString(cursor.getString(indiceColunaTarefa));
 textoRiscado.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), 0, textoRiscado.length(), 0 );
```

E depois simplesmente adicionei o objeto textoRiscado à lista itens.

```
itens.add(textoRiscado);
```

Funcionou perfeitamente

Answer (score 5):

Espero que isto ajude.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);
    tv.setText("Texto com risco");
    tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Comment: Em um textview funciona. Mas como fazer isso em uma ListView? Isso que eu não to conseguindo aplicar